# Display more than 1000 records in a dynamic parameter field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

My field has more than 3000 possible values but the dynamic parameter only displays up to 1000. How can I display every entry in the list?

[image]

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far, and what are you struck at?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: @manetsus There's no error message to share, and there's no user-defined code involved in this question. The user simply wants to know how to increase the displayed number of records.

Comment: @4444 You would be glad to know that, I got this question in the review queue of "Help and Improvement". FYI, a question comes to this review queue when it is determined by other review queues as very low quality and ill conditioned question. However, I have used a default message so that these things also came. I wrote those things having an intention to make it on-topic. Thanks.

Comment: @manetsus No worries, I figured it was something like that. Just making sure user3657503 isn't confused when they read your first message, because they don't really apply to this particular question.

Comment: @4444 Thanks for your cooperation. Your edit is also a good one. If I had remaining review in my hand, I would approve your suggested edit. Thanks.

Comment: have you checked all pages in dynamic paramter? like in picture it shows 1 go to 2 , 3 and till last page

Answer (score 2):

That's by design - it's an imposed limit to improve performance. You can increase that number by [**adding a registry key**](https://scn.sap.com/thread/977521). To paraphrase:

1. Create a registry key *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 11.**X**\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV*
2. Add string value "MaxRowsetRecords" and set it to 3000, or whatever you need.
3. Restart the machine

(Change the **X** in Step 1 to "0" or "5" depending on your release version.)

Comment: nice solution 4444

Comment: @4444 but you can see the entire list in 2,3 and till the last page in dynamic paramter field.. correct? can that be used?